# Looping through array of objects - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, spotify

I am trying to create a string of the artist's names from the `artists` array shown below (i.e. "Taylor Swift, Rihanna, Justin Timberlake"), but the `artist_obj` is undefined and I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". How do I fix this?

[image]

**Code**

```
 //Get info for each song
var artists = item["artists"],
artist = "";
var artists_count = 0;

 artists.forEach(function(item) {
      var artist_obj = item["artists_count"];
      if(artists_count !== 0) {
           artist = artist + ", " + artist_obj["name"];
      } else {
           artist += artist_obj["name"];
      }
      artists_count++;
 });
```

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere we can test it?

Comment: Without going to far into your code, when you do:`var artists = item["artists"], artist = "";`
It would set your artists array to null, so everything you try to get from it would return undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are accessing current object using index as `item["artists_count"]`. This wont work beacuase `"artists_count"` is a string & wont pass the varible value! You have to use `item[artists_count]` whichout double quotes to pass the variable! Apart from this you code is okay!

And please note that the argument, (i.e. *item*) you are passing to the `forEach` is the reference to the current object, thus there is no need to keep a separate variable to maintain & manually iterate the index.

Change your code to:

```
var artists = item["artists"],
artist = "";
var artists_count = 0; 

artists.forEach(function(item) {
      var artist_obj = item;
      if(artists_count !== 0) {
           artist = artist + ", " + artist_obj["name"];
      } else {
           artist += artist_obj["name"];
      }
      artists_count++;
 });
```

**A more clean version is:**

```
var artists = item["artists"],
artist = "";
artists.forEach(function(item) {
     artist = artist + item["name"] + ", ";
});
artist = artist.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

but I think your issue is on this line artist = **artist** + ", " + artist_obj["name"];

On the first definition the bolded artist should be undefined. What do you want artist to be at that point? I apologize I can't add a comment since I'm new to Stack Overflow and you have to have a rep of 50 points.

Comment: Which is why you can answer questions for real until you have 50 rep

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let list = [];
let artist_count = 0;

artists.map(artist => {
    list.push(artist.name)
    artist_count ++;
});

list.join(',');
```